# Database call stuck at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

Calls made from Java to SQL server using jtds driver is stuck. We have checked there is no locking or any long running queries on SQL server.

Following is the stack trace from java thread dump. Any one has any idea?

```
"core-CommandInvoker-thread-7133" prio=5 tid=7362 @@@@ RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:146)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:128)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsData.readData(TdsData.java:767)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsRowToken(TdsCore.java:3172)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2430)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:802)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next(JtdsResultSet.java:608)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:20
```

7)

Comment: Hello, how did you solve this problem? Im currently facing the same issue on a Sybase database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today on `Java 8 / JDBI / Postgresql / HikariCP`.

Mysteriously adding `order by` to the query solved the problem.
To be more specific, the resultset needs to be in deterministic order. If there're any ties in the `order by`, it'll stuck on `socketRead0`.

Here is [an old report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56411) that leads me to this solution.